# Connecting to PostgreSQL as root through psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, supervisord

I'm trying to run a Python service using `supervisord`, which needs to be run as root (`sudo supervisorctl`). The Python service tries to connect to PostgreSQL using `psycopg2` through a call that looks like:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db_name user=user_name")
```

When doing that I received the error `FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "user_name"`. I've also tried

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db_name user=postgres")
```

but receive the same error message. From the command line it's possible for me to do 
`sudo -u postgres psql db_name` and have everything work as expected. `sudo -u user_name psql db_name` also works.

In short, I'm trying to figure out how to connect to PostgreSQL using `psycopg2` when the Python process is run as root.

Comment: Is there a good reason to run it as root?

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to specify the host so that `psycopg2` doesn't use sockets:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="dbname", user="username", host="127.0.0.1")
```